# Write and read errors with Valgrind

Tags: c, memory, binary, char, valgrind

I try to convert a integer in a binary format and I want the result in a char*, so I have this code :

```
unsigned int_to_int(unsigned k) {
    if (k == 0) return 0;
    if (k == 1) return 1;                       /* optional */
    return (k % 2) + 10 * int_to_int(k / 2);
}

char* tab_binaire(int nb){
    char* str = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*8);
    sprintf(str, "%d", int_to_int(nb));
    int zeroManquant = 8-strlen(str);V
    char* res= (char*) malloc(zeroManquant*sizeof(char));
    for (int i = 0; i < zeroManquant; i++) {
        res[i]='0';
    }
    strcat(res,str);
    free(str);
    str=NULL;
    return res;
}
```

I already try to put the exit character at the end of the string but I always put the errors.
Here are my errors :

```
==10789== Invalid read of size 1
==10789==    at 0x483B924: strcat (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==10789==    by 0x1097C3: tab_binaire (automate.c:145)
==10789==    by 0x10983F: main (automate.c:161)
==10789==  Address 0x4a54ae4 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==10789==    at 0x483874F: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==10789==    by 0x109787: tab_binaire (automate.c:140)
==10789==    by 0x10983F: main (automate.c:161)

==10789==
==10789== Invalid write of size 1
==10789==    at 0x483B940: strcat (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==10789==    by 0x1097C3: tab_binaire (automate.c:145)
==10789==    by 0x10983F: main (automate.c:161)
==10789==  Address 0x4a54ae4 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==10789==    at 0x483874F: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==10789==    by 0x109787: tab_binaire (automate.c:140)
==10789==    by 0x10983F: main (automate.c:161)
==10789==
==10789== Invalid write of size 1
==10789==    at 0x483B94F: strcat (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==10789==    by 0x1097C3: tab_binaire (automate.c:145)
==10789==    by 0x10983F: main (automate.c:161)
==10789==  Address 0x4a54ae8 is 4 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==10789==    at 0x483874F: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==10789==    by 0x109787: tab_binaire (automate.c:140)
==10789==    by 0x10983F: main (automate.c:161)
```

**Here is my main()...**

```c
 int main(int argc, char const argv[]) { 
    char binaire = tab_binaire(12); 
    printf("%s\n", binaire ); 
    liberer_binaire(binaire); 
    return 0; 
    }
```

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  Amongst other things, it is missing the needed `#include` statements for `string.h`  and `stdlib.h`  and `stdio.h`

Comment: OT: regarding the statements: `char* res= (char*) malloc(zeroManquant*sizeof(char));` and  `char* str = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*8);`  1) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest removing the cast.  2)  the expression `sizeof( char)` is defined in the standard as 1.  Multiplying the parameter by 1 has absolutely no effect.  Suggest removing that expression.  3) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: regarding: `int main(int argc, char const argv[]) {`  Since neither of the parameters are used, the compiler will output two warnings messages about the unused parameters.  suggest using the signature: `int main( void )`

Comment: in function: `main()` this statement: `char binaire = tab_binaire(12);`  The function: `tab_binaire()` returns a pointer to char, not a char, so this statement does not compile.  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to get the same results

Comment: OT:  the posted code only contains less than 30 lines, however; the messages from valgrind are indicating statements in the range 140, 145, 161.  Please post the actual code that is causing the problems.  In general, post messages for the code that you have compiled

Comment: regarding: `int zeroManquant = 8-strlen(str);V`  That trailing `V` does not compile.  BTW: how do you know that the length of the string `str` is >= 8?

Comment: the posted code passed the `malloc`d memory `str` to free(), but fails to pass the `res` to free()`.  The result is a unrecoverable memory leak

Comment: the posted code calls the function: `liberer_binaire(binaire);`, but you have not posted the contents of that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following adjustments (You had some problems in your code):

```
unsigned int_to_int(unsigned k);
char* tab_binaire(int nb);
unsigned int_to_int(unsigned k) {
    if (k == 0) return 0;
    if (k == 1) return 1;                       /* optional */
    return (k % 2) + 10 * int_to_int(k / 2);
}

char* tab_binaire(int nb){
    char* str = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * 9);
    sprintf(str, "%d", int_to_int(nb));
    int zeroManquant = 8 - strlen(str);
    char* res= (char*) malloc(9 * sizeof(char));
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < zeroManquant; i++) {
        res[i]='0';
    }
    res[i] = '\0';
    strcat(res,str);
    free(str);
    str=NULL;
    return res;
}

int main(int argc, char const argv[]) { 
    char *binaire = tab_binaire(12); 
    printf("%s\n", binaire );
    free(binaire);
    //liberer_binaire(binaire); 
    return 0; 
    }
```

The *valgrind* errors above means that you're trying to access memory (*read* or *write*) which is out of the area allocated for the variables.

After filling the start of the string `res` by `'0'` using the `for` loop, you needed to put the null character `'\0'` at the end so the `strcat` copy the second string from this position.

At this point:

```
char binaire = tab_binaire(12);
```

You were assigning a pointer to char so you had types conflict, it's simply fixed as follows:

```
char *binaire = tab_binaire(12);
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to add in res the end string character I really want to add the '0' character to put the string in a normalized format in 8 bits

Comment: @TomRibardiere, Ah you didn't mention that before, but can you try the updated answer, it's supposed to work as you expect it now.

Comment: Yes now the binary number is in the good format but I have always the same valgrind errors

Comment: ah, that's come from `malloc(zeroManquant*sizeof(char));` try change it to `malloc(9 * sizeof(char));`

Comment: It settle a lot of error but i have always one.`==15275== Invalid write of size 1
==15275==    at 0x483B94F: strcat (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)

==15275==    by 0x1097D0: tab_binaire (automate.c:146)
==15275==    by 0x10984C: main (automate.c:163)
==15275==  Address 0x4a54ae8 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==15275==    at 0x483874F: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==15275==    by 0x109784: tab_binaire (automate.c:140)
==15275==    by 0x10984C: main (automate.c:163)`

Comment: Did you try to add more length to in `malloc` for `res` ? char* res= (char*) malloc(10 * sizeof(char));

Comment: yes it solve the error but can you explain me how ?

Comment: The problem was that the memory location that the `strcat` was trying to write in is outside of the memory addresses allocated for that process. in other word, You didn't allocate enough memory for the whole string in addition to the terminating null char `'\0'`